# ‘internalPath’ (type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’) to type ‘std::basic_string<char>&&’

Tags: c++, string, c++11, gcc

I am running below line of code from a function

```
string internalPath(os.str());
   m_tags.insert(make_pair<string, TagConfig >(internalPath, tagConfig ));
```

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘make_pair(std::string&, const wicom::TagConfig&)’
m_tags.insert(make_pair<string, TagConfig >(internalPath, tagConfig ));
                                                                    ^
```

Compiler g++=C++14

Answer (score 3):

You should never specify template arguments expicitly for `std::make_pair`—it is intended for deducing them, as it uses perfect forwarding. Either get rid of them:

```
m_tags.insert(make_pair(internalPath, tagConfig ));
```

or if you need to specify them explicitly, use `std::pair` directly:

```
m_tags.insert(pair<string, TagConfig >(internalPath, tagConfig ));
```

---

As a side note, you seem to have `using namespace std`; somewhere. I suggest you get rid of it, it's obfuscation more than anything else.

Comment: @trideceth12 "it is intended for deducing them, as it uses perfect forwarding." It cannot deduce them for perfect forwarding if you specify them explicitly. The *only* difference between using `std::pair` and `std::make_pair` is whether you specify template arguments or not. If you want to specify them explicitly, use `std::pair`.